# Ckeditor/KCFinder 2.x uploading image not working on server but working locally

Tags: php, file-upload, kcfinder

I am using ck-editor for my website. Successfully integrated and everything worked fine both local and production but image upload option not working on the server. 
I am getting the error below, while "browse server" button
"The address wasn’t understood"

the "browse server" button works on local but on the live server doesn't work
[image]

the kc-finder image:popup neither display existing images nor upload the new one.
 but if pop-up url run on a new tab it works fine(the pop-up mode doesn't work.)
[image]

after click "upload button" (on firefox browser). the browser doesn't understand the URL